# Cannot see a pipeline for my branch after creating one on my GitHub repository and pushing a commit

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

I have a `multi branch` `pipeline source` set up to create pipelines for any new branch on my GitHub repo
But when i create a new branch and push a commit also the branch is not showing up as a pipeline

I tried searching for the pipeline with the my specific branch but it does not show up

Answer (score 0):

I was able to manually fix it by going to the `pipeline source` page and manually fetch the branches(there is an option called `Fetch branches` on the `multi branch` source) for my repository and sync my specific branch in it